# How to create a generic groupByIndex function?

Tags: scala, generics

I would like to have `groupByIndex` function that groups values based on their index (and not the value).
A concrete method definition for `Vector[A]` could look like the following:

```
def groupByIndex[A, K](vector: Vector[A], f: Int => K): immutable.Map[K, Vector[(A, Int)]] = {
  vector.zipWithIndex.groupBy { case (elem, index) => f(index) }
}
```

Testing this function in the REPL gives indeed the correct result:

```
scala> val vec = Vector.tabulate(4)(i => s"string ${i+1}")
vec: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(string 1, string 2, string 3, string 4)

scala> groupByIndex(vec, i => i%2)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Vector[(String, Int)]] = Map(1 -> Vector((string 2,1), (string 4,3)), 0 -> Vector((string 1,0), (string 3,2)))
```

Now, I would like to apply the "enrich-my-library" pattern to give this method to all the classes that should support it, i.e. classes that implement `zipWithIndex` and `groupBy`. Those two methods are defined in `GenIterableLike` (`zipWithIndex`) and `GenTraversableLike`/`TraversableLike` (`groupBy`).

With all this in mind, I tried to mimic the method definitions of `zipWithIndex` (this is the problematic) and `groupBy` to build my own `groupByIndex`:

```
implicit class GenIterableLikeOps[A, Repr](val iterable: GenIterableLike[A, Repr] with TraversableLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  def groupByIndex[K, A1 >: A, That <: TraversableLike[(A1, Int), OtherRepr], OtherRepr](f: Int => K)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (A1, Int), That]): immutable.Map[K, OtherRepr] = {
    val zipped = iterable.zipWithIndex
    zipped.groupBy{ case (elem, index) => f(index) }
  }
}
```

First, this seems way too complicated to me - is there a way to simplify this? For example, can we somehow drop the second `OtherRepr`? (I was not able to.)
Second, I am not able to call this function without explicitly specifying the generic parameters. Using the example from above I get the following error:

```
scala> vec.groupByIndex(i => i%2)
<console>:21: error: Cannot construct a collection of type scala.collection.TraversableLike[(String, Int),Nothing] with elements of type (String, Int) based on a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String].
       vec.groupByIndex(i => i%2)
                       ^

scala> vec.groupByIndex[Int, String, Vector[(String, Int)], Vector[(String, Int)]](i => i%2)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Vector[(String, Int)]] = Map(1 -> Vector((string 2,1), (string 4,3)), 0 -> Vector((string 1,0), (string 3,2)))
```

How do I a) simplify this method and b) make it work without having to specify the generic parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute the `OtherThat` type parameter by `That`. That way you get rid of `OtherThat` and solve the problem of having to specify the generic type parameters. The compiler is then able to resolve `That` by looking at the implicit value for `CanBuildFrom[Repr, (A1, Int), That]`.

```scala
implicit class GenIterableLikeOps[A, Repr]
    (val iterable: GenIterableLike[A, Repr] with TraversableLike[A, Repr]) 
    extends AnyVal {

  def groupByIndex
      [K, A1 >: A, That <: TraversableLike[(A1, Int), That]]
      (f: Int => K)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (A1, Int), That])
    : Map[K, That] = {
    val zipped = iterable.zipWithIndex
    zipped.groupBy{ case (elem, index) => f(index) }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as good as the other answer, but if you don't care about what you're building, one way to simplify and avoid building the zipped collection:

```
implicit class gbi[A](val as: Traversable[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def groupByIndex[K](f: Int => K) = (as, (0 until Int.MaxValue)).zipped.groupBy { case (x, i) => f(i) }
}
```

The range is a benign way to avoid taking the size of the traversable.